# How to order a list of dictionaries by value when each dictionary has a different key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts:

```
dicts = [{'ENE001SOLC': 3},
 {'TRN002SIGN': 4},
 {'ENE001SOLC': 4, 'TRN002SIGN': 3},
 {'TRN002SIGN': 3},
 {'TRN002SOLC': 3, 'SAL016DECL': 3},
 {'ENE001SOLC': 5, 'SAL016DECL': 3},
 {'ENE001SOLC': 4}]
```

I want to sort this list by the values in each dict in descending order (higher comes first). I have visited a lot of posts already but all of them provide solution to sort the list when the values of the keys are the same for each dict, but this is not the case. The expected output would be somethinglike this:

```
[{'ENE001SOLC': 5, 'SAL016DECL': 3},
{'ENE001SOLC': 4, 'TRN002SIGN': 3},
{'ENE001SOLC': 4},
{'TRN002SIGN': 4},
{'TRN002SOLC': 3, 'SAL016DECL': 3},
{'ENE001SOLC': 3},
{'TRN002SIGN': 3}]
```

How can i do this?? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: this is very inconcise. I already tried with this but it seems to work when the keys have all the same name all over the dicts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this `sorted` command and the sorter will be the maximum of the value, why do I need `-`, so I make the number negative, if I don't the order will be low to high:

```
print(sorted(dicts, key=lambda x: -max(x.values())))
```

For a pandas `Series` do:

```
dicts = dicts.to_frame()
dicts[1] = dicts[0].apply(lambda x: -max(x.values()))
dicts = dicts.sort_values(1)
print(dicts[0])
```

Output:

```
5    {'ENE001SOLC': 5, 'SAL016DECL': 3}
1                     {'TRN002SIGN': 4}
2    {'ENE001SOLC': 4, 'TRN002SIGN': 3}
6                     {'ENE001SOLC': 4}
0                     {'ENE001SOLC': 3}
3                     {'TRN002SIGN': 3}
4    {'TRN002SOLC': 3, 'SAL016DECL': 3}
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great!! Exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Sure!! I still have to wait 9 minutes though

Comment: @Miguel2488 yeah i know

Comment: Just one ore question please, what if the list was actually a pandas series? If i use this method to order my pandas series it works, but i'm loosing my index values and they are important because this series comes out from a `groupby` operation. Is there anyway to perform the same sorting  operation assuming that my list is in fact a `pd.Series`?? Thanks again

Comment: @Miguel2488 Can you accept now i added the series solution

Comment: It worked just nice @U10-Forward. A big thank you 

Answer (score 8):

You could use `sorted` and order the lists according to the maximum value found in the inner dictionaries' values:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(dicts, key=lambda x: max(x.values()), reverse=True)

[{'ENE001SOLC': 5, 'SAL016DECL': 3},
 {'TRN002SIGN': 4},
 {'ENE001SOLC': 4, 'TRN002SIGN': 3},
 {'ENE001SOLC': 4},
 {'ENE001SOLC': 3},
 {'TRN002SIGN': 3},
 {'SAL016DECL': 3, 'TRN002SOLC': 3}]
```

Comment: In fact yes, this is not matching the order i wanted, it has to come in descending order by value

Comment: Thank you, this is much better!! :)